# Sending email using mutt

Tags: linux, mutt

I have a problem sending an e-mail using mutt. When i use a simple command like this:

```
echo "msg body" | mutt -s "subject" my_addresss@com.pl
```

I get no error messages (in the fact no messages at all). Unfortunatelly as I check on my box no email has been sent. How can I check/get to know what went wrong? Is there a way to tell mutt to display any info/status about sended msg?

Comment: Enable verbose logging. I'm not sure how but if you search Google for "mutt verbose logging" you should find it. Tra checking here: http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#tab-commandline-options and use the option for debug logging.

Comment: Try the syntax from here http://askubuntu.com/questions/470417/email-body-empty-when-i-use-echo-in-mutt-commandline-mode-with-root-account

Comment: Is there a mail server configured in mutt? Are there any messages on the mailserver on your local host? (`/var/log/mail*`)